# .NET CORE 3.1 Razor Page calling API returns nothing on IIS Server returns data locally

Tags: json, authentication, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I have a C# .Net Core 3.1 Razor Page where I am calling a 3rd Party API. When I run it locally in debug it returns a full JSON and is parsed into a strongly typed class successfully, but on the server hosting within IIS in process it fails with a 500 error that looks like an empty JSON object

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0
```

I am using an AJAX call to a Razor handler method. The website is using oAuth2 to authenticate the user (this is an intranet application) and this part works as expected both locally and on the server. My suspicion is that the user is "authenticated" locally (through windows or some other method and that data is being sent to the API) but on the server the Claims are validated but not passed to the API. I have used Postman on the server to validate the API can be reached. I have also contacted the API host and verified the request is not failing from the API, its not even reaching it. It requires HTTPS on port 443 which I confirmed is open between the server and the API.

Here is the Razor page method (called from AJAX).

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetPerson()
        {           
                var userInfo = await whitePages.GetPersonByIDAsync(ID);               
                return new JsonResult(userInfo);
                             
        }
```

This calls a function within an Interface

```
   public async Task<Models.PeopleAPI> GetPersonByIDAsync(string id)
        {
           
               string uriString = createGetPersonByidUriString(id); //This just builds the https string
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uriString);
                List<Models.PeopleAPI> people=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.PeopleAPI(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return people.Single(); // use Single to guarantee only one result was receieved, otherwise throw an exception
                       
        }
```

My peopleAPI model is as follows.

```
 public class PeopleAPI
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string NTID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string UnixID { get; set; }

etc
etc
}
```

Please help, I have tried adding in user credentials to make the API call, various other Stack suggestions (5 to 10 different approaches, sync, async, etc) and just cannot seem to come to a solution (each one works locally, but not on the IIS server).

HELP!!!

Comment: That means the response coming back from the server is not json or is not properly formatted json. You have to look at the response. It could be an error page sent back from the server in html format, which can't be parsed into proper json. If could be json that has invalid tokens. It could be json that has been serialized twice. Can you post what the response body looks like?

Comment: Any idea how to grab the response body on the server? I have tried to debug it but have a hard time grabbing the message.

Comment: You run your middleware locally for debug (pointing to the remote API) then invoke the call from a local client and debug the middleware with breakpoints. That is one way.

Comment: It works perfectly locally when I run it. NOt sure if running the middleware locally is something different than putting it all on the server.

Comment: Here is what is coming back from the request on the server, note the API is running correctly (some HTML removed for brevity). 

`<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: ""
</FONT>

<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.`

Comment: I have also confirmed with wireShark that no traffic is leaving the server and hitting (or heading too) the API.

Comment: More details, it looks like the traffic is still going out on http PORT 80 versus on https port 443. The API rejects http port 80. How can I force the call to be on the correct port?

Comment: In most cases, you can simply change the endpoint address for your API from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Same results, even tried using the port in the address. Guess it has to be something else. Again I am no wireshark expert but it looks like it tries to resolve the name at the DNS server IP address and then stops.

Comment: I was able to solve my own issue using the visual studio remote debugging on my server. It turns out the local debug on my machine was not using the proxy server (System.Net.Http.HttpWindowsProxy was showing empty) but on the server it was using a different version (system.Net.Http.HttpEnvironmentProxy) and using the default proxy specified within netsh winhttp proxy. Once I set the startup.cs to specify the AddHttpClient I also included the useProxy = false. This was within an intranet and hope maybe someone else can use this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my own issue using the visual studio remote debugging on my server. It turns out the local debug on my machine was not using the proxy server (System.Net.Http.HttpWindowsProxy was showing empty) but on the server it was using a different version (system.Net.Http.HttpEnvironmentProxy) and using the default proxy specified within netsh winhttp proxy. Once I set the startup.cs to specify the AddHttpClient I also included the useProxy = false. This was within an intranet and hope maybe someone else can use this in the future.

```
services.AddHttpClient("coolapi", c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://something.com/");              
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = false
            }) ;
```